# Heroku not resetting database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am attempting to reset my database on heroku using this:

```
heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE
```

and then run:

```
heroku run rake db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

I have noticed by going into the heroku rails console that the users are not being dropped and thus this validation has failed.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Are these users part of your seed data?  Could you be inadvertently seeding twice?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. `heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE` is not clearing the data in the shared db. According to documentation on heroku, this seem to the right thing to do. I am not sure if there has been some recent change which is not document or if there is an issue with heorku.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:
`heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE --confirm {the name of your app}`

Substitute the name of your app where I have written {the name of your app}. For example, if your app is called my_great_app then you use:

`heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE --confirm my_great_app`

To recreate the database with nothing in it:

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

To populate the database with your seed data:

```
heroku rake db:seed
```

You can combine the last two into one action by executing this:

```
heroku rake db:setup
```

Comment: When I try this I get: "Unknown database: SHARED_DATABASE. Valid options are: DATABASE_URL, HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT_URL" - any ideas?

Comment: I haven't used Heroku for a while now, so I'm guessing that their API's have changed. I would suggest getting in touch with Heroku support, or posting another question here on SO.

Comment: Thanks - I'll ask support.

Comment: @VoA instead of `SHARED_DATABASE`, just use `DATABASE_URL` -- yep, that exact phrase. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been through this, here is what I did (step #3 was missing from the other answers which stalled me for a while):

1. heroku pg:info  (to get the value of HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_HEROKUCOLOR_URL)
2. heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_HEROKUCOLOR_URL --confirm {app_name}
3. heroku run rake db:schema:load
4. heroku run rake db:migrate
5. heroku run rake db:seed

As per: [Heroku rake db:migrate does not create tables (Rails 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58106064/heroku-rake-dbmigrate-does-not-create-tables-rails-5)